# do not addClass if option is checked

Tags: jquery, css

On the website I have a button with an addClass statement. 
Before this button is clicked there is a possible option to check a radio button. 
Is it possible to **not** add the class if the button is checked?

**The current code:**

Radio button:

`<input type="radio" name="test_name" id="test_id" value="0" title="test_title" 
onclick="$test_click" class="radio" /><label>radio text</label>`

Button:

`<button type="button" title="button_test" class="button" onclick="addClass();">
    button text</button>`

addClass statement (working):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addClass() {
$j('.test').addClass('test2');  }
</script>
```

Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addClass() {
if($(test_id).attr("checked") != "checked"){
       $j('.test').addClass('test2');  
     }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector and do something like:

```
function addClass()
{
    if (!$j("#test_id").is(":checked")) {
        $j(".test").addClass("test2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function addClass() {
  if($("#test_id:not(:checked)")[0]){
      $('.test').addClass('red');  
  }
}
```

iif `#test_id` is [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) then add the required class.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/unetal

Comment: @Sailes: Please accept the answer that helped you the most (by clicking the tick outline next to the answer).